# cant figure out how to index, match, and use the if function combined in a table

Tags: excel

I currently have a column in my table called "leave weighting" which gives a value of 1 or 0.5. the formula is below. i want to now improve on this formula and make it do exactly what it does now if column "leave taken as" says days, if column "leave taken as" says hours instead, i want it to give the value that is in column "hours taken"

```
=INDEX(TblLeaveWeight[Weight],MATCH(INDEX(TblAnnualLeaveType[[#All],[Weighting]],[@[Leave ID]]),TblLeaveWeight[Leave weight],0))
```

The "leave taken as" column is calculated like this

```
=INDEX(TblEmployeeList[#All],MATCH([ID],TblEmployeeList[[#All],[ID]],0),5)
```

Comment: I would suggest you to share some sample data for different scenarios and the expected outcome. You may or may not need INDEX for this task depends on what you want to achieve ultimately.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself sheesh im a genious, thanks a bunch Terry W LUL

```
=IF([@[Leave Taken As]]="Days",(INDEX(TblLeaveWeight[Weight],MATCH(INDEX(TblAnnualLeaveType[[#All],[Weighting]],[@[Leave ID]]),TblLeaveWeight[Leave weight],0))), [@[Hours Taken]])
```

Comment: Good work, but just because you were able to solve your problem on your own does not mean you provided us with the proper information to do so